# Present tense in a question with verb in past tense

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, questions, sequence-of-tenses

I have got following two questions.

> I wanted to ask am I correct in thinking that we can’t test token system?
>
> I wanted to ask was I correct in thinking that we couldn't test token system?

I want to know which of the two is correct.

In both the question I have mentioned *I wanted to ask* (which is past tense)

In #1 I have written
*Am I correct* (which is present tense),

but in #2 I have written *Was I correct* ( which is past tense).

Can we write a question in present tense followed by a past tense?

Comment: I read through this question a few times and felt like I didn't understand English anymore. Formatting helps a great deal.

Comment: I edited a bit.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify why exactly you think it would be right or wrong. It is not clear what your difficulty is with them.

Comment: Why have you written "I wanted to ask" in the *past* tense? Do you mean that *yesterday you wanted to ask it*, but *today you've changed you mind and no longer want to ask it*? If you *still* want to ask it, surely changing the first part into the *present tense* would solve your problem?

Comment: Additionally and alternatively, when did the 'thinking' take place? Where you thinking it *yesterday* - but *not today*? Or are you still thinking it *today*?  We can't advise you what is correct, if we don't know what you are trying to say.

Comment: @TrevorD: Thanks for your comment. I understand it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are looking for but here are some valid examples

Meeting John now

> *Hi John, I want to ask you if I am correct in thinking that we can’t test token systems*

Wanted something yesterday - past tense of wanted

> *Yesterday I wanted to ask you if I am (still) correct in thinking that we can’t test token systems*

Wanted something for a while

> *Glad I bumped into you since I wanted (for a while now) to ask you if I am (still) correct in thinking that we can’t test token systems*

Thinking it at an earlier date - *was correct*

> *I wanted (or want) to ask you if (when I saw a suggestion yesterday) I was correct in thinking that we can’t test token systems*

Comment: How about a chance meeting? "Aha! I'm glad I've seen you, because I wanted to ask whether we can test token systems"

Comment: Notice ... in all these cases he has *can't* and not *couldn't*, which I agree with.  Unless you are asking about the ability to test token systems in the past which may be different than that ability today.

Comment: Andrew - yes that would work too :)

Comment: I was having this confusion that if part one was past tense then second part had to be past tense also. I was having this confusion because I was considering the mentioned examples as same as reported speech. I know these examples were not reported speech but I was kind of confused.